# Is it possible to bruteforce a file encrypted with a keyfile?

Tags: encryption, passwords, openssl, entropy

If someone used a keyfile (4092 bit of entropy) to encrypt a file, and bruteforced it with Hashcat... would Hashcat have to guess the blob data in the keyfile to crack the encrypted file?

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=keyfile.key bs=4092 count=1 

$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -A -in filename.txt -pass file:keyfile.key -out filename.txt.enc

$ cat keyfile.key

@<��B�M�����Yj�TO
               @    d��_G���ݘ`k�M�?�բ�Ƃ��-�b��f(a�Bѩ=> Ξ�U
�uE��s��k���$�N�����/ĢI�HK�N���`�������Js�3�zX>F=�Xy�t˵ǜ�NK�ZA7ݺrˤ��>��0R�n�k�T8gbX�����8��� ��v�
                                                                                                    �~6�    ,���;�*{U{�+]�%N]������Y��(�JT�@Т��������
�~p@�p��R�rU�_�(��3��9- k�Ɛ��v-}7���\o_��pJ�@�<jc���$S
�rwi�2�6��������R4ȓ�B鶒o�7����}���MВcBU0�t_^9�@�d)
��{Gg|@m~8�g΅��<�
*3ByPHvO�%

                                              ��D�YXR&�7}k���L�u�Bj���44yj��j�w选a��R��@���NO����q  �
```

Comment: Documentation says the "first line" of the file is the password. So, it might just read up to the first 0x0a byte in the your keyfile (first newline character). The documentation I read did not specify other limitations. However, if you are using AES256 then I'm not sure how the key could possibly "use" more than 256 bits, so there must be some kind of reduction in entropy that occurs.

Comment: You should never use `cat` on a binary file. Use `hexdump` instead.

Comment: @hft It hashes the line as if you passed it with `pass:blahblahblah`. Older versions use MD5, newer versions use SHA256. The specific algorithm can be chosen with `-md`. So, in theory, you could have a larger password, but naturally a hash would reduce it to the size of the cipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, hashcat cracks *hashes*, while AES is a block cipher. Are you sure hashcat can even do AES? I don't see it listed in [the hashcat manpage](http://manpages.org/hashcat).

Let's assume it can, and take [this hashcat benchmark](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/1495#issuecomment-360154897) of 250MH/s on a single GTX1080 as our cracking speed. 2<sup>4096</sup> possibly keys divided by 250 million guesses per second = 1x10<sup>1206</sup> x age of the universe [[source: wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E4096%20%2F%20(250%20million%20%2F%20second))].

*(Also, where on earth did you get a 4096-bit AES key from? If you're using AES-256, then it's probably only using the first 256 bits of the keyfile. 2<sup>256</sup> / 250MH/s is down to only 1x10<sup>51</sup> x age of the universe.)*

Then you'd face the problem of "how does hashcat know when it gets the right key?" For that, you'd need to know something about what plaintext you're expecting to see in the encrypted file.

---

**TL;DR:** It's *possible*, provided A) hashcat supports block ciphers, B) you know something about the plaintext you're expecting, C) you're willing to wait 1x10<sup>51</sup> x age of the universe for it to complete.

Comment: I think you're missing a major problem with OP's command. The `file:keyfile` will only read until the first newline and hash it with MD5 or SHA256. If the file is binary, then it very likely could only be using a three byte key (trivial to brute force). I would be careful implying it's so secure...

Comment: @forest where do you get three bytes from? Sounds like you should post an answer and I'll learn something :)

Comment: Three was just a random number. If the file started with `0x41 0x9f 0xa4 0x0a`, then it would indeed result in a three byte password. Anyway this was already explained in [a comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196722/is-it-possible-to-bruteforce-a-file-encrypted-with-a-keyfile/196723?noredirect=1#comment390896_196722).

Comment: ... but the OP can't mark a comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: I've written an answer, in hopes that OP reads it and learns what is wrong with his command.

Answer (score 2):

First I need to point out that Hashcat would not be the right tool for the job. Hashcat works on hashes, and OpenSSL does not store the hash of the key. Instead, you would need to have at least one block of known plaintext, after which you can attempt to brute force a key that results in that plaintext being encrypted into the ciphertext that you see in the file. There are other tools that can do this.

However, I believe you are misunderstanding how the command you have specified actually works. Unfortunately, OpenSSL does not take keyfiles. When you give it a password in the form of a file, it takes only the first line as the password. This line is processed exactly as if you passed it via `pass`. That is, it is hashed once with SHA-256 to form a 256-bit value that is used to key AES. Because the file you are using is binary, it is very possible that a newline character (0x0a) is one of the first bytes.

If a newline byte happens to be within the first eight or so bytes, it will be absolutely possible to brute force the resulting encrypted file. The probability that any given byte is a newline is 1/256. The chance that a newline is present in the first eight bytes is only 1/32. This means that there is no guarantee that it will not be possible to brute force a file that you encrypt improperly by passing a binary file as the key.

---

So, how would you do this *correctly*? You'd want to hash the keyfile yourself and pass the hash as a key to the OpenSSL command. This can be done easily using common utilities:

```
pass=$(sha256sum keyfile.key | awk {'print $1'})
```

You can then pass this key to OpenSSL by using `-pass pass:$pass`. This will guarantee that the entropy of the key will be no less than the entropy of the keyfile you give it. For a 4092-bit keyfile, hashing it with SHA-256 would result in a 256-bit key. Brute forcing that would require going through up to 2<sup>256</sup> cipher operations which, as the other answer mentions, would not be possible to complete before the universe itself ends, assuming of course the 4092-bit keyfile is truly random.